# UStruct: type must be a UCLASS, USTRUCT or UENUM

Tags: unreal-engine4

I’m probably missing something simple but I can’t find it. The struct is marked as USTRUCT() but still it complains about it not being a USTRUCT. It’s not caused by the TArray because removing that still gives the same error. Also I can use the struct FCrusherTrigger in blueprints without a problem at all. But c++ gives me an error.

````
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FCrusherTrigger
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "CrusherTrigger")
    ECollisionShapeEnum CollisionType;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "CrusherTrigger")
    FTransform RelativeTransform;

    FCrusherTrigger()
    {
        CollisionType = ECollisionShapeEnum::CollisionShape_Box;
    }
};


...

// BaseCrusher.h
public:
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere, Category = "BaseCrusher")
TArray<FCrusherTrigger> TriggersSetup; // <<<<<<<<<<<<< error here ```
````

Comment: Post the full code, it's not clear if the struct is defined in the same file where you are using it as type or somewhere else. That error usually indicated a missing header but without looking at the full code there is no way to know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Change GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY() to GENERATED_BODY()

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your constructor above your properties, and call it public. My guess, the issue is around your Construct.